# Deleting groups of grid files based on pixel cluster size (under 10)

Tags: qgis, clustering, grids-graticules

I am new to QGIS, and I am currently using flood modeller to produce a series of surface water maps. Once the data is ran, I get a series of 10m2 grid tiles with varying Z flood Values. We are only intersted in clusters of tiles that intersect to be over 100m2 big collectivley, meaning any tile that isn't in a group of 10 needs to be taken out for the purpose of mapping. As the files are quite large, they result in many small clusters and single grid squares.

Is there a way I can group edit these tiles out to save time, instead of manually selecting them?

Below is an example of the clusters, those that intersect to complete 10+ files are the ones that I want to keep.

[image]

Below is another issue I am having which I hope you can advise on. The data in green is being left out of the cleaning, whilst the brown are being cleared. The diagonal brown line of grid squares represents a watercourse which needs to remain in the study as collectively, it is a cluster of over 10 squares and whilst I recognise that, the values are being included in the cleaning process (I believe this is because they don't intersect?).

Is there a way to include these diagonal values as a collective when calculating area, so that they are left in, or is this something I will have to do manually?

[image]

Comment: I guess "flood modeller" is a plugin? What data type does it produce?

Comment: @Erik, the program Flood Modeller is a simulation program, using LiDAR and rainfall data, to produce estimates of flooding events. In this case, the data being produced varies from .prj to .dbf and autocad shapefiles, showing depth/ probabiltiy of expected flooding in that area. Hope this helps?

Comment: @Anon no, the data being produced is most likely a shapefile with all necessary additional files based on what you describe. You could `dissolve` the shapefile based on the flood values, then run `multi to single part` and finally use `select by attribute` based on "$area >= 100" to extract all areas larger than 100 sqm.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for the help. Correct, the data is a shapefile containing the additional files. I must be doing something wrong, as the final select by attribut still does not seem  to select the clusters of squares I need? is this because I am typing in the wrong commands in the 'Operator' and 'Value [optional]' fields?

Comment: @Anon my bad, you need to use `select by expression`, sorry.

Comment: @erik thanks for your help, don't apologise!

Comment: @bera, I have updated the main question with a screen shot, hopefully this helps? and yes, I download vector data into QGIS. Once again, apologies if this is all worded horribly.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question, as per the [Tour].

Answer (score 2):

1. Dissolve
2. Multipart to Singleparts
3. Using the output from 2 calculate a field as:

`case when $area < grid area * 10 then 1 else 0 end`
[image]

4. Select features by expression features with `keep = 0`
5. Select by Location from your input Grid cells that intersect your selected single_parts, start editing and delete selected features

[image]

Comment: When on step 3. the 'Output Field Type' sections appear as the following; Float; Interger; String; Date. No sign of 'Decimal Number', and afterwards I appear to encounter the same issue with other methods. Could this be an issue with how I am uploading the vector layer?

Comment: Pick float. What issue is that? Maybe the Query is to "narrow", try something like: `case when $area < (10 * 10 * 1.05)`